# Chrome's onmessage() does not fire immediately after reconnect, despite receiving a message from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, websocket

I'm currently trying to create a websocket between chrome and a NodeJS server.
The Node server is using the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) plugin, and I'm using Chrome's default websocket handler.

Here are my lines of code for the server:

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.id = uuid();
  let response = {'type': 'uuid','data': ws.id};
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

And my code for the client:

```
//Listens for new messages
connection.onmessage = function(e) {
  let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
  console.log(data.data);
}
```

What I expect: The server generates a UUID for the client everytime they create a connection, and the client prints it to console. When the connection is severed and the client reconnects, the server sends a new UUID to the client.

What happens: The server generates a UUID for the client when they create a connection, and the client prints it to console. However, when the server goes down and comes back up, and the client re-establishes a connection, the server does send a new UUID to the client, but chrome just isn't picking it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: This is how I reconnect to the server

```
//Reconnect to server
setInterval(function() {
  if (connection.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
    reconnect = false;
    connection.close();
    console.log("Disconnected from server. Retrying...");
    connection = new WebSocket(server);
  } else {
    if (!reconnect) {
        reconnect = true;
        console.log("Reconnected to server.");
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

Edit 2: Modified the code, still doesn't work:

```
//Webhook
//On connection open
connection.onopen = function() {
  console.log("Connected to server");
  reconnect = "";
  //Reconnect to server if disconnected
  connection.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection closed, reconnecting...");
    //Retry every second
    reconnect = setInterval(function() {
        if (connection.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
            connection.close();
            console.log("Connecting to server...");
            connection = new WebSocket(server);
        }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

`onopen()` does not fire on reconnections either, so the client will try to reconnect every second after disconnecting, and will never stop.

Comment: If the client reconnects to the server, are you sure the `onmessage` listener is set on the new connection ? Can you include your reconnection handling in your question ?

Comment: _realisation_ I'll get back to you in a bit @Seblor

Comment: @Seblor how would I go about doing that? Do I wrap `onmessage` into `onopen`? I added the way I reconnect into the main question above.

Comment: Exactly. You should initialize all your listeners when the websocket opens its connection.

Comment: Also, instead of using a setInterval to check if the connection is still alive, you can add a listener to the `onclose` event that will be fired when the server closes (or crashes), then attempt to reconnect (and maybe use the setinterval if you want to make multiple attempts in case it fails the first time). This will be better in term of performances since you don't have to perform the same check every time.

Comment: @Seblor Hey, I took in your suggestions, but it still does not work. I've edited the question with the modified code.

Comment: The issue here is still the same : you are reassigning `connection `, so `connection.onopen` is back to `undefined`. By the way, to stop a setInterval, you need to use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval), reassigning the variable won't work.

Comment: Ok, how do I make it so that `connection.onopen` is not set to undefined? Surely I can't nest `connection.onopen` in itself. @Seblor

Comment: Create an initialization function that will take a websocket connection as parameter and will set its `onopen` listener. Then call this function in the reconnection handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found a solution**

```
//Webhook
function connect() {
  //Attempt to connect to server
  if (firstConnect) {
    console.log("Connecting to server...");
    connection = new WebSocket(server);
  } else {
    if (connection.readyState !== WebSocket.OPEN) {
      connection.close();
      console.log("Connecting to server...");
      connection = new WebSocket(server);
    }
  }

  //On connection open
  connection.onopen = function() {
    firstConnect = false;
    console.log("Connected to server");
    clearInterval(reconnect);
  }

  //Listens for new messages
  connection.onmessage = function(e) {

 }

   //Reconnect to server if disconnected
   connection.onclose = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection closed, reconnecting...");
    connect();
  }
}
```

When you create a new socket connection, chrome will repeatedly try to connect on its own until it times out. Timing out will fire `connection.onclose`, which in turns calls `connect()`.

By nesting it all in `connect()`, the event handlers will be hooked onto the new websocket connection everytime. Furthermore, you will not need to `setInterval()`, thus avoiding any performance issues.

Browsers tested on: Chrome, Opera, Safari